# Floated element must never get out of the div

Tags: html, css

Following my code:

HTML:

```
<div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    <span>test</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    width: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    word-break:break-all;
}
span{
    float: right
}
```

I would get this result: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2py25w1.jpg 
I would like the text right-floated should not have to get out the div, so it must go to a new line inside the div when needed, as in the code that I posted. 
In this case, for example, there is no need to let go of the text in a new line, because the text fits on the right of the text: http://jsfiddle.net/3kRan/2/

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3kRan/3/?

Comment: Didn't even think about @j08691 solution; I guess I assumed you didn't want the text outside of the `span` to be right aligned/floated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the overflow on your div to hidden like so:

```
div{
    width: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    word-break:break-all;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Your contents are overflowing when the span tries to float. This will allow your span to stay within its parent container.

Comment: The span will stay within the parent container, but it won't break to a new line like the image indicates the goal to be.

Comment: As he said, he only want the text to break to a new line "when needed."

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on your ability to wrap your text in an element, such as `p`.  The ending result would be:

```
<div><p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
  <span>test</span>
</div>
```

```
div{
  width: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  word-break:break-all;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; /* fix to clear the parent */
}
p {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
span{
  float: right
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kRan/5/